# How to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory in your PATH?

Tags: laravel, bash, ubuntu, directory, path

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and I've been trying all possible methods to install Laravel to no avail. Error messages everything I try. I'm now trying the first method in the quickstart documentation, that is, via Laravel Installer, but it says to "Make sure to place the `~/.composer/vendor/bin` directory in your `PATH` so the Laravel executable is found when you run the Laravel command in your terminal." so my question is, how do I do that? This may be a simple question but I'm really frustrated and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 593, accepted):

To put this folder on the PATH environment variable type

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

This appends the folder to your existing PATH, however, it is only active for your current terminal session.

If you want it to be automatically set, it depends on the shell you are using. For bash, you can append this line to `$HOME/.bashrc` using your favorite editor or type the following on the shell

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

In order to check if it worked, logout and login again or execute

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

on the shell.

PS: For other systems where there is no `~/.bashrc`, you can also put this into `~/.bash_profile`

PSS: For more recent laravel you need to put `$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin` on the `PATH`.

PSSS: If you want to put this folder on the path also for other shells or on the GUI, you should append the said `export` command to `~/.profile` (cf. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

Comment: Works like a charm here, on ubuntu 14.04.
You might wanna logout/login and/or open a fresh terminal window if things don't seem to work.

Comment: You should use `$HOME` instead of `~` in the composer path. Not sure about bash, but it is certainly necessary when you're setting it in zsh's `.zshrc`.

Comment: It should be noted that on Ubuntu 16.04 running laravel 5.1, the path is:     ~/.config/composer/vendor/bin

Comment: Alternatively, I needed to edit my ~/.zshrc as I'm using oh-my-zsh with iTerm2. Otherwise... same instructions... cheers!

Comment: I have tried this, no luck! Also I do not have a directory called ./composer/vendor. I only have .composer and in there i have a cache folder.. Been searching for 2 days now.

Comment: absolute champion. thanks mate. waisted 10 min trying to do it. your solution worked like a charm

Comment: echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
was missing the .config directory
THEN execute
source ~/.bashrc

Comment: Both .composer/vendor/bin and .config/composer/vendor/bin contain "laravel" for me on Ubuntu 16.04 for what it's worth, so both work.

Comment: Works on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: For Linux Mint 20.2 it was `$HOME:~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Get the path by composer it self: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69125272/2873481

Answer (score 142):

Detailed instructions:

in your ~/.bashrc add these lines:

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

Then reload:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Check if its added correctly:

```
echo $PATH

/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/web/bin:~/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Comment: Thx! I'm not too familar with unix and this made total sense! (And dollars!)

Comment: The thing I echo $PATH does not include the composer part.. I have literally added it over 100 times in all the possible ways, rebooted about 5 times an reloaded bashrc.. nothing. Any idea?

Comment: source ~/.bashrc    ---   I have to do this each time i should laravel. This is the best answer for me

Answer (score 68):

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with composer globally installed, this worked for me.

Edit the .bashrc file in your home directory puting the path to the composer bin folder that is located in /your/home/.config/composer/vendor/bin

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc
```

If not works, verify the path to the composer bin directory and close and reopen the terminal. Otherwise, try to logoff and login in the Ubuntu.

Also works in ubuntu 18.04. Thanks @chifliiiii for your feedback.

Comment: Worked with Parrot OS 3.8

Comment: This works, when you run composer laravel installer, it changes directory to Changed current directory to /home/username/.config/composer
./composer.json has been updated as per the path in this answer

Comment: This is the one that worked for me on ubuntu  17.10. Thanks.

Comment: Worked like a charm on 20.04.

Answer (score 40):

For setting the PATH on Yosemite (OS X 10.10.5), use the command below:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

To reload either quit terminal and start up again or use:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Helped me, hope it helps someone else out there!

Comment: Thank you @forca001 in my `.zshrc` it was not working using `~` and it finally did with `$HOME`

Comment: Nice! This worked for me as well on Mac OS X El-Captain.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me on my Mac running OSX Mojave. Thanks heaps!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked with MacOS Majave 14.x

Answer (score 14):

I did all of the above and it didn't work for me.

I just copied this into my terminal and it worked for me.

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Comment: @grit45 can you please explain why it worked a little bit

Comment: This question is about putting some directory on the path and not how to install composer.

Answer (score 10):

my path didn't have /.composer, just /composer so my path was:-

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
```

This worked for me on ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 9):

This is for setting PATH on Mac OS X Version 10.9.5.

I have tried to add $HOME because I use user profile :

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

When you do not use user profile:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then reload:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 5):

Open the Mac Terminal:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

If you haven't used vi, it may look a little funny at first, so enter the following code carefully, in order:

```
i
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

PRESS ESC

```
:
w
```

PRESS ENTER

```
:
q
```

PRESS ENTER

Now you should have returned to the normal terminal view.

Check that composer now has the correct path:

```
cd ~/.composer
echo $PATH
```

If you see the path including your file directory, (e.g. /Users/JeffStrongman/.composer/vendor/bin), you're good to go.

```
cd
```

Then run your installation. I ran into this problem, while configuring my Mac to use Laravel Valet.

Example (optional)

```
valet install
```

Answer (score 4):

In case someone uses ZSH, all steps are the same, except a few things:

1. Locate file `.zshrc`
2. Add the following line at the bottom `export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH`
3. `source ~/.zshrc`

Then try `valet`, if asks for password, then everything is ok.

Comment: With ZSH, I would rather set `$path` with `path=("$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin" $path)`.

Comment: Path with `~` may not work in ZSH. This works for me (Laravel 10+, Ubuntu 22+, Composer 2.7+, ZSH)... `echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 4):

For me in Ubuntu 22.04, this works:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
```

Answer (score 3):

For Linux Mint 18: edit ~/.bashrc and add this line to it at the bottom:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
```

then resource .bashrc (type in console):

```
source ~/.bashrc (or close and reopen the terminal)
```

test it by typing in the console:

```
echo $PATH
```

or type in console:

```
laravel
```

Answer (score 3):

The Composer bin directory is set and stored in [`bin-dir`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md#can-vendor-binaries-be-installed-somewhere-other-than-vendor-bin-) config variable and can be different depending on your setup. Running the command `composer global config bin-dir --absolute` will tell you the absolute path to your global composer bin directory. Using this command you can modify your `.bash_profile` to add it to your `PATH` exactly how it is configured.

```
# Add Composer bin-dir to PATH if it is installed.
command -v composer >/dev/null 2>&1 && {
        COMPOSER_BIN_DIR=$(composer global config bin-dir --absolute 2> /dev/null)
        PATH="$PATH:$COMPOSER_BIN_DIR";
}
export PATH
```

Comment: Nice, can avoid the `/dev/null` redirect using the quiet `-q` flag too. For those using fish the command is `fish_add_path (composer global config bin-dir --absolute -q)`.

Comment: I ended up using this answer, as `composer global config bin-dir --absolute` work on any Linux distribution I could be using. There is no need to find out where the directory is, when Composer tells you where it is.

Answer (score 3):

**add environment variable into  `bashrc` file**

**For Ubuntu 17.04 and 17.10:**

```
echo 'export PATH="~/.config/composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

**For Ubuntu 18.04**

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

**to Check environment variable working or not first reload the `bashrc` file**

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

if not working any method then First Check Where is install  **Composer**  to Check Run This Command :

```
locate composer -l 1
```

then Copy Output add output into this line and run again command.

```
 echo 'export PATH="OUTPUTHERE/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

After Successfully Laravel Command Work Give a Permission To Parent Folder (for example u are using apache server than give permission to apache web listing directory like that)

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER -R /var/www/html/
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding *export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin" to ~/.bashrc* works in your case because you only need it when you run the terminal.
For the sake of completeness, **appending it to PATH in /etc/environment (*sudo gedit /etc/environment* and adding *~/.composer/vendor/bin* in PATH)** will also work even if it is called by other programs because it is system-wide environment variable.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 2):

MacOS Sierra User:

make sure you delete MAAP and MAAP Pro from Application folder if you have it installed on your computer

be in root directory `cd ~`
check homebrew (if you have homebrew installed) OR have PHP up to date

`brew install php70`

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"`

`echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

`source ~/.bash_profile`

`cat .bash_profile`

make sure this is showing : 
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"

`laravel`

now it should be global

Comment: you have saved my time, i was searching for 2hr

Answer (score 2):

AWS Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Linux ws1 4.15.0-1023-aws #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 16:31:06 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

Worked for me.

Comment: What is the improvement to the existing answers?

Comment: Seems to work for me

Answer (score 2):

**On Fedora:**

Some composer bins are not in the .composer directory
So you need to locate them using:

```
locate composer | grep vendor/bin
```

Then echo the the part into the .bashrc

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/{you_composer_vendor_path}"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Mine was `"/.config/composer/vendor/bin"`
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 16.04

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: What is the improvement to the existing answers?

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it works on osx:

lunch your terminal

```
 nano ~/.bash_profile
```

And paste

```
 export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

press control + x

press the y key

press the return / enter key

Answer (score 0):

this is what I added in my .bashrc file and worked.

`export PATH="$PATH:/home/myUsername/.composer/vendor/bin"`

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem make sure you find the path of composer.phar first

example mine is something like this

```
alias composer="php /Users/Your-username/composer.phar"
```

Go to cd Users > Your user > Command ls and see if composer.phar is there if yes then add the above line to your .bash_profile. Make sure you change the username to your own.

Hope this help you out

Answer (score -1):

I've tried a lot of solutions, but on **Ubuntu 20.04** only this worked for me:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```