# Laravel PHP command not found

Tags: php, laravel, bash, composer-php, command

I installed Laravel using Composer without problems, but when I try to run `laravel` in the terminal, I get the following error:

> -bash: laravel: command not found

The docs say that I need to do the following:

> Make sure to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory in your PATH so the laravel executable is found when you run the *laravel* command in your terminal.

How can I do that?

Comment: What is your PATH variable value?

Comment: How can I obtain that? With echo $PATH?

Comment: type `echo $PATH` in Terminal / bash , etc.

Comment: /Users/chema/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Eclipse/sdk/platform-tools:/Applications/Eclipse/sdk/tools

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel installation: How to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory in your PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373188/laravel-installation-how-to-place-the-composer-vendor-bin-directory-in-your)

Answer (score 375, accepted):

Ok, I did that and it works:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

And paste

```
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

do `source ~/.bash_profile` and enjoy ;)

**Important**: If you want to know the difference between *bash_profile* and *bashrc* please check this [link](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html)

**Note:** For Ubuntu 16.04 running laravel 5.1, the path is: ~/.config/composer/vendor/bin

**On other platforms:** To check where your Composer global directory is, run `composer global about`. Add `/vendor/bin` to the directory that gets listed after "Changed current directory to ..." to get the path you should add to your `PATH`.

Comment: restart the terminal doesn't work in my case. I need to source ~/.bash_profile as well

Comment: this is not the correct answer >>  .bashrc file (not .bash_profile).

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. I didn't have any `.bashrc` file and I do not want to create one with dependency to `.bask_profile`

Comment: @NaingLinAung great tip , It won`t work without that tip ..
But why if i close the terminal after working , it restop working ??

Comment: For anyone coming here, make sure you have laravel installer installed globally also: `composer global require "laravel/installer"`

Comment: Would be great to make the note about Ubuntu 16.04 (well i'm on 18.04) super bold and super red and super large font.

Comment: PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH in ~/.profile on ubuntu16.04 did the trick for me

Comment: even after that i still get the same error, any idea on what to do?

Comment: for me it was `export PATH=$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH`

Comment: ``` export PATH="~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"  ``` Work form me in ```.bashrc``` not in ```.bash_profile``` in Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 264):

Add the following to `.bashrc` file (not `.bash_profile`).

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

at the end of the file and then in terminal run `source ~/.bashrc`

To verify that:

`echo $PATH`

(Restart the terminal, Check & Confirm the path is there)

Run the laravel command!

Note:
*For Ubuntu 16 and above use below:*

```
export PATH="~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: You can find more information about the differences between these hidden files: http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html

Comment: late reply. hope it helps someone. check this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42537/why-must-i-source-bashrc-every-time-i-open-terminal-for-aliases-to-work. if you use .bahrc you need to reload every time. so add that in .bash_profile

Comment: I had to add ~/.config to the path.. depends on where the binary is

Comment: It might be the '/root/.config/composer/vendor/bin' for linux distros

Comment: `export PATH="~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" ` - the life saver on Ubuntu 18.04! :)

Comment: even after that i still get the same error, any idea on what to do?
i have installed laravel as shown here: https://snipboard.io/BpvM8s.jpg
and added the PATH as shown here: https://snipboard.io/7zy6qJ.jpg

Comment: did you close the terminal and opened again to check the same?

Comment: This `export PATH="~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" ` worked for me in Ubuntu 22

Comment: ```export PATH="~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" ``` this work for me to solve my problem in Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 110):

When using MacBook, refer to the snippets below;

For fish:

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' >>  ~/.fishrc
source ~/.fishrc
```

For zsh:

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' >>  ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

For Bash:

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: This overwrites your current zsh config. Do >> instead of >.

Comment: Unable o login to my system after running above command .Please help me.

Comment: For my Ubuntu server it was export PATH=~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH

Comment: even after that i still get the same error, any idea on what to do?
i have installed laravel as shown here: https://snipboard.io/BpvM8s.jpg
and added the PATH as shown here: https://snipboard.io/7zy6qJ.jpg

Answer (score 89):

Solution in [link](http://tutsnare.com/laravel-command-not-found-ubuntu-mac/). In the terminal:

```
# download installer
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
#setting up path
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" 
# check laravel command
laravel 

# download installer
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"

nano ~/.bashrc

#add

alias laravel='~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel'

source ~/.bashrc

laravel

# going to html dir to create project there
cd /var/www/html/
# install project in blog dir.
laravel new blog
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the alias on my virtual machine, adding the folder to the PATH didn't help for some reason.

Comment: you can use ``composer global require "laravel/installer" `` too

Comment: In Homestead I needed to set the laravel alias folder to this one instead `/home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor /bin/laravel`

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04. I also added the alias at ~/.bashrc
`alias laravel='~/.config/composer/vendor/bin/laravel'`

Comment: This works for me.  Exporting the path to `~/.profile` does not do it.  That step with `~/.bashrc` is necessary.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 just adding `alias laravel='~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel'` was enough

Answer (score 45):

**Type on terminal:**

```
 composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

**When composer finish, type:**

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

**Paste and save:**

```
export PATH="~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

**Type on terminal:**

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Open another terminal window and type: laravel

Comment: this one not working for me. But this worked : 
`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"`

Comment: Looks like some composer versions use .config and other .composer. This was the answer that worked for me, without needed to add an alias or anything. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers!! This finally worked! for easy placement `echo 'export PATH="~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc` load it with `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: For Windows User : First step is enough if you installed composer as default

Comment: Just this worked for Laravel 10 on Arch linux. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 41):

If you're using Ubuntu 16.04.

1. You need to find the composer config files in my case is :
   `~/.config/composer` or in other cases `~/.composer/`
    
   you can see the dir after this command 
   `composer global require "laravel/installer"`
2. after Laravel Installed you can find your laravel in `~/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/`. 
   and you will find the *Laravel shortcut command* in here : 
   `~/.config/composer/vendor/bin/`
3. set your .bashrc using `nano ~/.bashrc` and export your composer config file :

   `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"`
   or you can use allias. but above solution is recommended.

   `alias laravel='~/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel'`
4. Now refresh your bashrc using `source ~/.bashrc` and then laravel is ready!!

above steps works with me in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Why is it I need to type in source ~./bashrc everytime I want to use laravel new etc??

Comment: @Paul501 `source ~/.bashrc` is used to refresh the new setup in the file. So you can't have the new setup running in the current user session if you don't use `source`

Comment: for more info you can read it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518127/how-do-i-reload-bashrc-without-logging-out-and-back-in

Comment: `alias laravel='~/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel'` did the trick for me!

Comment: This solution still works on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: worked for me in ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 23):

For zsh and bash:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"

source ~/.zshrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

For bash only:

```
export PATH=~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH

source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 18):

For Developers use `zsh` Add the following to `.zshrc` file

`vi ~/.zshrc` or `nano ~/.zshrc`

```
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

at the end of the file.

`zsh` doesn't know `~` so instead it by use `$HOME`.

`source ~/.zshrc`

Done! try command `laravel` you will see.

Comment: Mentioning about zsh doesn't know ~.  Saved my day!

Answer (score 13):

If you are on macOS or *nix just run this in your terminal:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 7):

For those using Linux with Zsh:

**1 - Add this line to your `.zshrc` file**

```
export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

**2 - Run**

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

- Linux path to composer folder is different from Mac
- Use `$HOME` instead of `~` inside the path with Zsh
- The `.zshrc` file is hidden in the Home folder
- `export PATH=` exports the path in quotes so that the Laravel executable can be located by your system
- The :$PATH is to avoid overriding what was already in the system path

Answer (score 7):

If you are coming here 2021 this has worked for me also using Ubuntu 16.04

```
nano ~/.bash_profile 
export PATH=$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
ctrl+x and save 
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: This help me in 2024. Please follow this method

Answer (score 4):

I set the PATH,but it didn't work.I find other way to solve it. **(OSX 10.10 & laravel 5.2)**
1) find the executable file:

```
~/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel
```

2) give execute permissions:

```
chmod +x ~/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel
```

3) make a soft link to `/usr/bin:`

```
sudo ln -s /Users/zhao/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel /usr/bin/laravel
```

Answer (score 4):

For **MAC** users:

**1.** Open terminal

```
cd ~
```

**2.**   Double check the $PATH

```
echo $PATH
```

**3.** Edit file

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

**4.** PASTE

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

**Don't forget** to put quotation marks.

**5.** control + X (y + enter to save the file and exit)

Now start vagrant, go to your folder and try:

```
laravel new yourprojectname
```

Answer (score 3):

**type on terminal:**

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

**then paste:**

```
export PATH="/Users/yourusername/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

**then save (press ctrl+c, press Y, press enter)**

**now you are ready to use "laravel" on your terminal**

Answer (score 1):

If you have Composer installed globally, you can install the Laravel installer tool using command below:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer...

Composer 1.10.1 2020-03-13 20:34:27
laravel --version
Laravel Installer 3.0.1

Put
export PATH=$PATH:~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
in your ~/.zshrc or ~/.bashrc
source ~/.zshrc or ~/.bashrc
This works

Answer (score 0):

Composer should be installed globally:
Run this in your terminal:

```
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Now composer commands will work.

Answer (score -1):

My quick way of creating a new project

//install composer locally on web root - run the code from: https://getcomposer.org/download/

Then install laravel:

```
php composer.phar require laravel/installer
```

Then create the project without adding anything to any path

```
vendor/laravel/installer/bin/laravel new [ProjectName]
```

//add project to git

```
cd ProjectName
git init
git remote add origin git@...[youGitPathToProject]
```

Wondering if this way of doing it has any issues - please let me know

Answer (score -3):

Just use it:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel youprojectname
```