# Laravel: command Not found

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I feel like a moron for having to ask this, and I've gone through all the similar questions to no avail.  I am running Ubuntu 14.04 in a vagrant vm on a mac.  I have composer installed and i have run these commands:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

(this appears to have worked and shows that laravel is one of things that was downloaded)

I have also added this line to the .bashrc

```
export PATH="∼/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Note, i added this to both the vagrant user as well as the root users .bashrc file.  I have logged out and back into the shell and verified the path with this command:

```
echo $PATH
```

Which gives me this:

∼/.composer/vendor/bin:∼/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

and the command itself that fails is this

```
laravel new test
```

I don't see what i could be missing, any ideas?

Comment: did you run the commands in the VM? or your machine? I have a similar setup, and run them in my machine

Comment: I didn't try this but it seems a little odd.  not wrong necessarily but it seems as though you have your laravel installer and composer installed on your host machine rather than on the vm.  Perhaps this does make sense actually as you could have one version of composer/laravel and several VM's.  my question to you is what is your host operating system?  not sure if composer will run in Mac OSX

Comment: yeah, I use OS X El Capitan. Composer runs great in OS X (at least in Lion, Mountain Lion, Mavericks and El Capitan)

Comment: to solve the problem you need to find the compose config files location. And then fix the export PATH http://stackoverflow.com/a/41476969/2652524

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It is better to use `$HOME` instead of just `~`.

In my `.zshrc`(I use [zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/)) I have it working this way

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

Make sure your terminal does actually use `.bashrc` and not maybe `.bash_profile`, if that is the case you should edit that file.
If you are using it from the VM, the user you log in with when you call `vagrant ssh` is `vagrant`, not `root`.

In addition, remember to source the file after the edit, or open a new terminal.

#### UPDATE

I see there are answers that put the `$PATH` after composer's path, so I thought I could tell you what I learned to be the difference.

It's not a random thing you can put whatever way you want. **What you put after overwrites what comes before**. You're gonna need to know it if you want to use packages that overwrites anything installed in paths that are already in `PATH`.

That means that if you have something installed on your system and you install a newer version of the package using composer, it will have the same command to start so if the composer path will not be **after** the system path, you'll have to reference the full path to the binary inside composer's `vendor/bin` to execute it.

Comment: This worked for me.  Actually both answers here were correct but i'm giving you the point because i also learned that the .bashrc is not always run.  I googled that and found out that it has to be listed in your .profile otherwise no bueno.

Comment: Does this not work wit Valet? I have installed the laravel installer AND have correct path.. Still I get the error.

Comment: @NicolasV make sure you installed Valet globally

Comment: @phaberest pretty sure I have, followed the Laravel docs.. Anyhow, I can manage with the composer way of installing Laravel.

Comment: Thanks @phaberest! I found that my bash file was actually `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Changing "~" to "$HOME" while using `fish` fixed the issue for me. Thank you! i.e. `set -U fish_user_paths "$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin" $fish_user_paths`

Comment: Great to hear mate ;)

Comment: This worked for me but my laravel bin was in an odd location. So I suggest if people are struggling to get this work they search for the lavavel bin. 

find ~/ -type f -name "laravel"

Then check your paths after you edit you edit your .bashrc 

echo $PATH

Make sure you have added the path with the laravel folder

Answer (score 11):

Open your terminal and run these given lines:

For zsh and bash:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"

source ~/.zshrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

For bash only:

```
export PATH=~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH

source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Don't copy your posts, nor make them link only. Either tailor each response for each question, or flag to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, @Frankerz. Now I modify the comment. And thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you put the tilde (~) inside quotes it won't be translated to your home directory. Run this and it should work:

```
export PATH=∼/.composer/vendor/bin":$PATH"
```

Comment: This also worked btw

Comment: Yeap! This worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using `Homestead` I found this one worked for me

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor"
```

Comment: actually it's export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin" anyway thanks for the clue man :)

Comment: Why do I have to use this command every time I create a new project? Is there a way to make this command permanent?

Comment: @ColinStadig have you read my answer? Put it in you terminal's config file.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to the accepted answer...

In case you are executing the commands directly on the terminal (in which case the path will remain available till the terminal window or tab closes)

If you mess up the earlier path, you need to open and close the terminal window (or tab)

Example:

first execute (mess up the path in someway)

```
PATH="test"
```

then execute

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
```

You will still get the error
Now close the terminal window or tab and reopen it and execute

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
```

And the error should be gone!

Answer (score 1):

paste this

```
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

and restart the termminal.

Answer (score 1):

Check if /root/.composer directory EXISTS, if does NOT exist then install composer like this:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

And install laravel again, after that your command will work.