# Bash command not found in laravel terminal

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, laravel-5

[image]

I want to edit my `composer.json` for adding html ad forms package.  But after editing, when I update my composer through command `composer update`, it gave me an error in the terminal:

> bash command not found

What could be wrong?

Comment: please dont make your whole question a link to an image

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below steps:

- You can run composer command in your terminal and check composer installed or not.
- If composer not installed then run below command in your terminal.

> ```
>   curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
> ```

**Or**

if another issue then follow this link ([Laravel PHP Command Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376516/laravel-php-command-not-found))

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score -1):

It seems you've not installed composer globally.

read the following:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx