# Cannot find ~/.composer folder after installing composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have installed composer by the instructions given in their site for Ubuntu 16.04. Its giving the usual output after giving the 'composer' command in the terminal. 
After installing composer, I have downloaded the composer using

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

Now to install Laravel, I have to add `$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin` in my path. But there is no .composer folder in my home directory. Can anybody tell me why this is happening ?

Comment: I know, its a hidden folder. I think its clear that I am posing this question as pressing clrl+H is not showing it.

Comment: Hello, I am still looking for a proper answer. Depending on that I will reinstall composer in my pc or take any other steps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: At Jan 2016, Composer respect XDG specifications https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/1407. You can find it inside `~/.config/composer/vendor/bin`

Answer (score 4):

In my Ubuntu 16.04.4, after downloading the Laravel installer using

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

I found my Laravel here :

```
~/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/
```

Then I set my .bashrc using `nano ~/.bashrc` and export your composer config file :

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
```

And refresh using `source ~/.bashrc` in terminal

And Laravel is running, but I did not need any `.composer` folder as said in the Laravel official site.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41476969/2414657) has helped me a lot.