# Laravel command not found on Debian

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I'm trying to run laravel and keeps returning command not found
I'm using the latest version of composer and laravel today. 
I think is laravel 5.7 and composer 1.7.2

I added `export PATH=/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH`
to the .bash_profile to  .bahs_profile.

Than I ran `source ~/.bash_profile`

Any ideia on troubleshooting?

I've looked all over stackoverflow and google nothing!

Comment: You can explicitly specify where is php and where is composer by /path/to/php /path/to/composer ...

Comment: For PHP /usr/bin/php and for composer
/usr/local/bin/composer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel PHP Command Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376516/laravel-php-command-not-found)

Comment: Alternatively use `composer create-project laravel/laravel my-project`

Comment: @rob006 I already check all solutions in that thread! :(