# "laravel: command not found" after installing Laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php

After I am using

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

it seems the installation is success. For the second time, the result is:

```
Changed current directory to /home/ryanadhi/.config/composer
Using version ^3.1 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
13 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
```

then if I do

```
echo $PATH
```

the result is

```
    ~/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/ryanadhi/go/bin:/home/ryanadhi/.composer/vendor/bin
```

However if I try

```
laravel
```

the result is always:

```
laravel: command not found
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? According to that output of `composer global require`, nothing has been installed

Comment: It was my second trial, that's why nothing has been installed/updated. the first one shows the installation completed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel PHP Command Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376516/laravel-php-command-not-found)

Answer (score 3):

Editing the `~/.bashrc` in Ubuntu 20.04 to reflect the path shown in the "Changed current directory to /home/ryanadhi/.config/composer" , message. fixed this for me.

first

```
 gedit ~/.bashrc
```

then edit the line

```
export PATH="/home/ryanadhi/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `/home/ryanadhi/.config/composer/vendor/bin` to your path.

The output that said "Changed current directory to /home/ryanadhi/.config/composer" means that `/home/ryanadhi/.config/composer` is your Composer global directory.

Comment: my path written like this `/home/ryanadhi/.composer/vendor/bin` so it is not correct?

Comment: Nope, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

If your still having issues running the laravel command you can symlnk laravel to /usr/local/bin/

Use this command:

```
ln -s ~/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/bin/laravel laravel
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had to do two things, first I needed the "~" in front of the path in the `bashrc` file. My path line was:

```
export PATH="~/home/stephen/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

and I had been putting "`sudo`" in front of "`laravel new...`" command which didn't work.

With those changes it installed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 11, I resolved this by running `composer global require laravel/installer`.