# How do I place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory in your PATH using .zshrc

Tags: laravel, zsh

This may be a very noob question, but I'm trying to install Homestead on my Mac. I'm following installation steps via http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead however there is a point in the installation process where it state "Make sure to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory in your PATH so the homestead executable is found when you run the homestead command in your terminal." How do I do this using zsh? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in whichever profile you're using (.zprofile or .profile or whatever), you would add the line:

```
export PATH = ~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

then reload your profile

```
source ~/.zprofile
```

Comment: How do I access .zprofile? I tried vi ~/.zprofile but it only creates a new file

Comment: Then you're not using .zprofile.  See which profile file you're using already; could be ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc, or ~/.zshrc.  there's a few more but those are the most common.

Comment: I can access ~/.zshrc however when I put PATH = ~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH , save and source ~/.zshrc I get /Users/username/.zshrc:83: command not found: PATH

Comment: Never mind, got it. added export PATH=/Users/username/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH

Thanks for your help Paul!

Comment: That "source ~/.zprofile" was what I was missing. Thanks

Comment: I had the same issue until I added `export PATH=/Users/username/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH`. I tried adding  `export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH` as recommended in the Laravel page but couldn't make it work, luckly I found this thread. Thanks @xslibx

Comment: I found for me I had to give the full path rather than using ~ then it worked.

Answer (score 11):

If your PATH is in **.bashrc** file :

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

If your PATH is in **.zshrc** file :

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Finally, you should restart your environment

`source .bashrc         #Bash`

`source .zshrc          #ZSH`

Comment: I had to type "source .bashrc" to make it work after

Answer (score 3):

Update the file ~/.bashrc like this:

```
PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:{$PATH}"
```

Answer (score 3):

**Setup**

Mac OS:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Linux:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin' >> ~/.zshrc
```

---

To apply **restart** terminal or:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

To check if it works:

```
echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

```bash
$ echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$(composer global config bin-dir --absolute --quiet)' >> ~/.zshrc
```

**TLDR;**

A bit more automatic approach to get **global** `vendor/bin` path:

```bash
$ composer global config bin-dir --absolute
/Users/me/.composer/vendor/bin
```

In currently open terminal updating `PATH` will work:

```bash
$ PATH=$(composer global config bin-dir --absolute --quiet):$PATH
```

As it's expected to have *global tools always available*, we can add it in `~/.zshrc` or others, plus:

- consider a difference should it be *prepended* or *appended* to the `PATH`,
- and use **single quotes**:

```bash
$ echo 'export PATH=$(composer global config bin-dir --absolute --quiet):$PATH' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 1):

In one of your start files within home directory (~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc)

```
export laravel=/Users/username/.composer/vendor/bin
export PATH="$laravel:$PATH"
```