# what is phpmd and how to use it?

Tags: composer-php, sublimetext3, ubuntu-14.04, phpmd

I have Ubuntu 14.04 + Sublime text 3 and installed phpcs packages

additionalty I have installed `phpcs`  and `php-cs-fixer`  on my system

From [this blog](http://theaveragedev.com/making-php-code-sniffer-plugin-work-in-sublime-text-3/)

I have found that **phpmd** (*PHP Mess Detector*) is also a required library, so installed **phpmd** as per given instructions on [official php md](http://phpmd.org/download/index.html)  page using alternative method ***From the github repository***  everything was finished.

```
:~/phpmd$ curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
#!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer successfully installed to: /home/keshav/phpmd/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
```

but now when I write on terminal

```
  phpmd /opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject, myfile.php
```

> **phpmd: command not found**

There is **phpmd** folder on Home directory and everything without any error.

I have local project on core PHP create `composer.json` in project folder as per suggested on [github](https://github.com/phpmd/phpmd) .

Please tell me what means by

> Then install Composer **in your project** (or download the composer.phar directly):

Comment: "phpmd (PHP Mess Detector) is also a required library" - required for what? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: required for  `phpcs` it was mentioned in the blog, link written in Question

Comment: phpcs does NOT require phpmd. These are separate tools.

Comment: @JakubZalas Thank you for the clarification. Now would you please tell me how to install and make it working on my ubuntu?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think the problem is you've installed phpmd in a local directory, but you're trying to use it as if it was installed globally.

Installation instruction on the referenced sites can't really be made any clearer. Since you've already installed phpcs and php-cs-fixer, and those work for you, just follow similar instructions for phpmd. These are all PHP projects and are installed in a similar way.

Anyway, to use phpmd as a global command you have several options.

**Github**

Clone the [github repository](https://github.com/phpmd/phpmd) just like you did and add the phpmd bin directory to [your `PATH` variable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path).

**Global composer installation**

Use the composer [global command](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global) to install phpmd globally. You will also need to make sure that composer's bin directory is in the `PATH`. By default it's `~/.composer/vendor/bin`.

```
composer global require phpmd/phpmd
```

This command will install phpmd globally, and as soon as `~/.composer/vendor/bin` is in your `PATH` you'll be able to call it by simply invoking `phpmd`.

It's very well explained in composer's documentation: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global

**Download the phar archive**

This is the simplest thing you can do. Simply go the phpmd [releases](http://phpmd.org/download/releases/index.html), [choose the latest](http://phpmd.org/download/release/2.1.3/changelog.html) and download [the phar archive](http://static.phpmd.org/php/2.1.3/phpmd.phar).

Put the phar file to whatever place you'd like. Just remember that it needs to be in your `PATH`. You can also rename it, to skip the `.phar` extension.

For example:

```
wget http://static.phpmd.org/php/2.1.3/phpmd.phar
sudo mv phpmd.phar /usr/bin/phpmd
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/phpmd
```

**Docker container**

First, fetch the docker image with [static analysis tools for PHP](https://hub.docker.com/r/jakzal/phpqa/):

```
docker pull jakzal/phpqa
```

One of the tools provided by the image is phpmd. The command below will run phpmd in a docker container and mount the current working directory as a /project.

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/project -w /project jakzal/phpqa \
    phpmd src text cleancode,codesize,controversial,design,naming,unusedcode
```

Comment: You will also need to make sure that composer's bin directory is **int** the PATH.  ??

Comment: You either need to add it to your PATH, or use the full path: ~/.composer/vendor/bin/phpmd. See the referenced documentation.

Comment: I have  **/home/<username>/phpmd** folder where `setup`, `src` and `vendor` folder resides  and  for PATH , I have `.profile`  http://pastebin.com/w6C12JUP

Comment: In case anybody wants to know how to add composer's bin directory in the $PATH : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373188/laravel-installation-how-to-place-the-composer-vendor-bin-directory-in-your#answer-26083661

Answer (score 4):

When you use the `composer`-based install, it gets installed into the `./bin` directory within the `./vendors` directory. So for me, relative to my project's root directory, it was here:

`./vendor/bin/phpmd`

And I was able to run it from my project's root by running `./vendor/bin/phpmd  . text codesize`. (I'm not getting any useful output yet, but another issue)