# Can't run Laravel vagrant box on Windows 7 machine

Tags: git, bash, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm trying to run vagrant homestead laravel virtual machine, but can't. I follow [official instructions](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead).

My steps:

1. Vagrant and VirtualBox installed successfully.
2. `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` downloaded.
3. `git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead`. I can't see any `*.yaml` file in root directory as I see in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=571&v=p0veZd9mtGc).
4. I open `Git bash` and go to `Homestead` folder, than type `sh init.sh`.

Output:

```
$sh init.sh
cp: overwrite `/z/.homestead/Homestead.yaml'?`
cp: overwrite `/z/.homestead/after.sh'?`
cp: overwrite `/z/.homestead/aliases.sh'?`
Homestead initialized!
```

But I can't see `Homestead.yaml` file. Also my `C:\Users\user\` folder not contains any `.homestead` folder.

6. `vagrant up`

Output:

```
 c:/projects/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:91:in `read': No such file or directory - Z:/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (Errno::ENOENT)
    from c:/projects/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:91:in `block in configure'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `add_config'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb:317:in `provision'
    from c:/projects/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:89:in `configure'
    from c:/projects/Homestead/Vagrantfile:20:in `block in <top (required)>'

    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in `each'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in `block in load'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in `each'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in `load'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:689:in `new'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:689:in `vagrantfile'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:441:in `host'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:207:in `block in action_runner'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:428:in `hook'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:671:in `unload'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/bin/vagrant:177:in `ensure in <main>'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/bin/vagrant:177:in `<main>'
```

What did I miss in my installation?

**UPDATE:**

I found these files in an already mounted disk Z:\ . Why bash creates files on `Z:\` when I start `init.sh` from `C:\`?

[Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) creates files in user profile folder (`.homestead` directory), but it also not making `vagrant up` to work.

**UPDATE 2:**

Now both `vagrant up` and `homestead up` commands give this output:

```
c:\projects\laravel5>homestead up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* A box must be specified.
```

Comment: for a windows installation, you can follow instructions from http://sherriflemings.blogspot.ca/2015/03/laravel-homestead-on-windows-8.html - I think you have a few variables wrong so it mounts a Z/ drive, the article will explain a step by step approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did it on Windows 7 and Windows 8 machines.

Steps:

1. Install `Git for Windows`.
2. Change HOME path by setting Windows PATH value. [Article how to do it](http://archive.gregk.me/2011/change-gitbash-home-directory/). Now if you type `cd ~` in Git Bash than you must move to your profile folder. Also Git Bash starts with the same folder.
3. Install `Vagrant` and `VirtualBox`.
4. Add Vagrant box `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`.
5. In your profile folder type `git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead`.
6. Create ssh keys in Git Bash by moving to `cd ~/.ssh` and type `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "yourmail@you" -f homestead`.
7. Move to `~/Homestead` and type `sh init.sh`. It creates 3 files in `~/.homestead` folder.
8. Edit your `Homestead.yaml` file. My config (`#` for comment line):

   ```
   ---
   ip: "192.168.10.10"
   memory: 2048
   cpus: 1
   provider: virtualbox

   #Paths to your generated SHH keys
   authorize: ~/.ssh/homestead.pub

   keys:
       - ~/.ssh/homestead

   #Folder sharing
   folders:
       - map: C:\projects\Laravels  <----your Windows mapped folder!
       to: /home/vagrant/Code   <--- VM mapped folder. Do not change it.

   #Add your sites here
   sites:
       - map: test.lar
       to: /home/vagrant/Code/test.lar/public
       - map: test2.lar
       to: /home/vagrant/Code/test2.lar/public

   #I commented it because do not want to re-create DB on each VM run
   #databases:
   #    - homestead

   variables:
       - key: APP_ENV
       value: local
   ```
9. Edit `hosts` file on `\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` folder and add 2 lines to the end:

   ```
   192.168.10.10  test.lar
   192.168.10.10  test2.lar
   ```
10. Now move to `~/Homestead` and start your machine with `vagrant up`. In most situations you need to run Git Bash as administrator. After this command you can see in VirtualBox running machine with name Homestead.
11. Open http://test.lar in browser on your host machine. You can see line `No input file specified.` All is OK.
12. SSH to homestead VM by typing `vagrant ssh` and become root user with `sudo su`.
13. If you want to create sites with `laravel` command, type this: `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`
14. Add composer global folder to PATH with `export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"` and `source ~/.bashrc`. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373188/laravel-installation-how-to-place-the-composer-vendor-bin-directory-in-your).
15. Move to laravel code folder `cd /home/laravel/Code` and create your first project with `laravel new test.lar`.
16. Refresh your http://test.lar page and see working page with `Laravel 5` on the center of the screen. It works! Files in your mapped folder are automatically synchronized.

That's all.
Mostly i used [this tutorial](http://sherriflemings.blogspot.ca/2015/03/laravel-homestead-on-windows-8.html) and [official](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1) in parts.

Answer (score 1):

I've followed the instructions on [Solg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558469/6167059) and they work well. Thank you very much! I didn't found this answer anywhere else.

There are some reservations, though. I've found out that if you `sudo su` before installing laravel with `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"` it will install laravel for the root user, and that is not what we should want, as it saves laravel on `/root/.composer` folder and it's only accessible by the root user.

A better aproach would be running `sudo composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"` without `sudo su`, so laravel gets fully installed with it's requirements, but in the vagrant user directory instead.

Actually, i've come up with an even better option (in my opinion) that is to put some code on the `after.sh`, located in `.homestead` folder, to be automatically executed when the VM goes up (by running `vagrant up`):

```
if [ ! -d $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin ]; then
    echo "Installing Laravel Installer!!!"

    sudo composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
    echo "\nPATH=$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" >>$HOME/.profile
fi
```

This way, even if you destroy your VM, when you `vagrant up`it again, laravel will be installed and `laravel` command added to bash.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Nice catch! Thank you. This world needs a good Homestead tutorial :))

Comment: You're welcome! Totally agree. Homestead is very useful, but some aspects of it are someway obscure, specially for non-linux users.