# Laravel "valet install" not found

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am trying to set up Laravels Valet ([Valet is a Laravel development environment for Mac](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/valet)). Everything works until it comes to the command "valet install". This command must be executed in terminal. But I got the error "command not found". Any ideas, why? Do I have to update my PATH or something else?

I switched to OS X a few days ago. Before that, I was a windows user. So I am a total newbie.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel installation: How to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory in your PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373188/laravel-installation-how-to-place-the-composer-vendor-bin-directory-in-your)

Answer (score 293, accepted):

Yes, you need to make sure that `~/.composer/vendor/bin` directory is in your system's `PATH`, you can check this by running:

```
echo $PATH
```

If you can't see it there, then you need to add this to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Comment: This is the answer I keep finding, EVERYWHERE! Yet it does not solve my problem.. valet is still `command not found`. Is there something else that might be overlooked for some inexperienced developers?

Comment: Maybe ur using zsh? If so add ~/.composer/vendor/bin to export PATH in ~/.zshrc

Comment: and if its still not working then u need to close and reopen the terminal.

Comment: For me using ubuntu18.04, this path is a bit different though. It's `~/.config/composer/vendor/bin/` for some reason.

Comment: Worked for me on High Sierra.

Comment: I modified the .bash_profile file directly using nano ~./bash_profile, added `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"` at end of file, saved, restarted terminal and it worked (I'm on Big Sur)

Comment: this is very helpful for m1 mac user like me

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. I was stuck at "command not found" after typing valet install

Comment: work for me on big sur

Comment: @nclsvh you must run ```source ~/.bash_profile``` after adding that line.

Comment: I got the same issue on my M1 Mac, I solved this with following command: 

`export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 69):

If you're getting the error message "**valet: command not found**", it's likely that PHP's Composer is not in your `PATH` variable, for instance:

```
$ valet install
-bash: valet: command not found
```

You can confirm if [Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet) was successfully installed by running the following command:

```
ls -al ~/.composer/vendor/bin/valet
```

If successfull, you'll see the symlink for Valet in Composer's `bin` directory pointing to Laravel in the `vendor` directory:

```
~/.composer/vendor/bin/valet@ -> ../laravel/valet/valet
```

**To test whether your `PATH` is missing Composer, try running the Valet command directly:**

```
~/.composer/vendor/bin/valet --version
```

If you're shown the Laravel version number, (e.g. `Laravel Valet 2.0.4`), this indicates Valet is installed but you need to [update your `PATH` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25373254/245264) to include Composer for the `valet` command to work globally.

In your Terminal, execute the following command which will append Composer to your shell's PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin
```

For the changes to take effect, you'll need to exit and re-open your Terminal window or tab.

Alternatively, you can simply source your shell's profile, which doesn't require quitting your active session:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

*If you have a different shell environment or you're using a shell other than Bash, you will need to source its configuration profile instead (e.g. `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, `config.fish`).*

Comment: This test flow worked for me, I had just forgotten to restart the terminal

Comment: The first steps seem to work, but when I try `source ~/.bash_profile`, I get `~/.bash_profile No such file or directory`, then weather or not I close and open a new terminal window, I still get `-bash: valet: command not found`.

Comment: This answer mentions paths including `~/.composer`, but I needed to change them to `~/.config/composer`, as other answers on this page mentioned.

Comment: Had to update my path to /.config/composer too. Otherwise this works great.

Comment: This flow worked perfectly for me using a M1 Mac, thank you!

Answer (score 39):

I'm using oh-my-zsh so:

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin" >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

You may replace `.zshrc` with `.bashrc`

Comment: This worked for me. Zsh seems to require the full path to your home folder, rather than `~/`.

Comment: What worked for me `echo "export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin" >> ~/.zshrc`

Comment: I've tried a ton of different posted solutions around the web for this and it was as simple as using $HOME instead of ~. Thanks!

Comment: @MohamedSaleh That works for me as well. :)

Comment: This worked for me too. Mac M1

Answer (score 23):

you just have to use:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

then

```
valet install
```

ready :)

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked for me.. My path before was pointing to '/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'

Answer (score 17):

Make sure that ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory is in your system's PATH, you can check this by running:

```
echo $PATH
```

If not there, open your ~/.bash_profile and add this code:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Then run:

```
composer global require laravel/valet --dev
```

Once it is done, run:

```
valet install
```

Answer (score 15):

If `valet install` doesn’t work, but `~/.composer/vendor/bin/valet --version` does work, try installing it via

```
~/.composer/vendor/bin/valet install
```

To See if that worked, check

```
valet --version
```

Answer (score 13):

If you're using zsh, you cannot use `~` as path to home dir, use `$HOME` instead.

In .zshrc file, instead of adding this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Add this and the path will resolve:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Comment: this is right in case for .zshrc also the location might be different like $HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin

Comment: This worked on my macOS Ventura as well by running the command export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 9):

If you have a fresh installation, you may not have the `PATH` variable contains your home path. So, adding the `$HOME` variable would require like the following:

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin`

Comment: Adding `$HOME/` before `.composer` does the trick! It seems ZSH doesn't understand or pull the correct directory using `~`.

Answer (score 7):

This command might solve your problem

```
test -d ~/.composer && bash ~/.composer/vendor/bin/valet install || bash ~/.config/composer/vendor/bin/valet install
```

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu 18.04 do this:

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Works with Ubuntu 20.04 As well

Answer (score 2):

with new composer installation, you need to add a new path which is

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.config/composer/vendor/bin
```

Then you need to

```
chown YOUR_USERNAME ~/.config
```

for accessing composer packages without sudo command.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed Composer **version 2** and found that composer default path is `~/.config/composer/` and similarly valet is also installed on `/.config/composer/vendor/bin/valet`.
So to solve this issues I added the composer path to `~/.bashrc` file as:

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:~/.config/composer/vendor/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `~/.composer/vendor/bin` directory to your `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 1):

For me worked

write in console

1. `cd ~/.composer/vendor/bin`
2. `pwd`
3. `copy pwd command result`
4. `export PATH=$PATH: (pwd command result)`
5. `valet install`

I think I explained well

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix on this website, and it fixed my issue.

```
test -d ~/.composer && bash ~/.composer/vendor/bin/valet install || bash ~/.config/composer/vendor/bin/valet install
```

https://hidayatabisena.medium.com/solving-issues-command-not-found-laravel-valet-install-on-macos-mojave-2a7629759a9f

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've to update /etc/profile file
added

> export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin

in

> /etc/profile

then

> source ~/etc/profile

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found the valet location by manual search

[image]

Then add the the valet file path to `PATH` variable

```sh
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then I ran the install command and it worked

```
valet install
```

Answer (score 0):

Php may be not installed

Use your prefered version with:

```
brew install php
// or
brew install php@8.0
// or
brew install php@7.4
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

**iTerm Terminal Users / ohmyzsh**

Step 1. `vi ~/.zshrc`

Step 2. mention below line anywhere

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Save, Exit & Open a new Terminal. That's it ✌️

Now type `valet -v`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just nid composer remove and install again next step you can download and install valet