# fish: Unknown command valet

Tags: laravel, valet

I'm trying to install Valet by iTerm Fish, but when start I get this error:

> fish: Unknown command valet

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you add Composer's `bin` directory to your `PATH`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085102/laravel-valet-install-not-found?rq=1

Comment: i did it but i get new error   [env: bash: No such file or directory] can you help me please

Answer (score 5):

If you run `echo $PATH` and don't see `~/.composer/vendor/bin` or whatever `~` equates to, then it's missing from you `$PATH`. To add it run:

```
set -U fish_user_paths ~/.composer/vendor/bin $fish_user_paths
```

Now when you run `echo $PATH` you should see `~/.composer/vendor/bin` and now be able to run `valet install`.

Sources:

- https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_path
- [Laravel "valet install" not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085102/laravel-valet-install-not-found?rq=1)