# Laravel Installation/Configuration - Command Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

Trying to install Laravel on Ubuntu Server 14.04. After installing PHP 7 I enter:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

I get: Composer successfully installed to: /home/ubuntu/composer.phar

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
composer
```

Works fine

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

I get:

[image]

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

I include this `export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"` at the very bottom.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Restart it

```
laravel
```

I get: "laravel: command not found"

Why does it not understand the command laravel?

Comment: Do you have `zip` and `unzip` installed on your Ubuntu Server ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel installation: How to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory in your PATH?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373188/laravel-installation-how-to-place-the-composer-vendor-bin-directory-in-your)

Answer (score 3):

I'm writing this answer for all the future Google searchers. I had a similar issue and I solved it in the following way:

First run:

```
sudo apt-get install zip unzip php7.0-zip
```

Then, edit your `~/.bashrc` file and append the following line:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

or

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
```

Which one is yours, depends on the line composer printed out during installation of laravel, followed by `/vendor/bin`. In my case (and in the case of the question), this was `$HOME/.config/composer`, so I had to do it the second way:
[image]

Don't forget to call

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

at the end. Enjoy Laravel!

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, I can see that there may be a chance the laravel packages were not installed correctly as you don't have `zip` and `unzip` installed on your system.

Run the following command to install these first and then try again to install laravel installer:

`sudo apt-get install zip unzip`

Regarding the `export PATH` use `$HOME` instead of the tilde `~` sign. Hope this will solve your problem. Seems like a path error.

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"`

Comment: That removed the orange error messages, but I still get `laravel: command not found`. Is the export PATH correct?

Comment: @Bxx Updated the answer. Try.

Comment: Tried it, but could not get it working. Still laravel: command not found

Comment: Can you type `echo $PATH`on your terminal and let me know what it shows?

Comment: @Bxx can I see how you have defined the path on your shell configuration file?

Comment: Revised: `~/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:‌​/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/ubuntu/.composer/vendor/bin`. Path in shell configuration file:  `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"`

Comment: can you `source` your configuration file and restart your terminal?

Comment: Entered this: `source ~/.bashrc` and restarted the terminal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114874/discussion-between-muhammad-sumon-molla-selim-and-bxx).