# laravel: command not found in Linux Mint 18

Tags: laravel

I am a newbie in Laravel and want to set up my first Laravel project. I am following the Laravel documentation. So far, I installed Composer and downloaded the Laravel installer using Composer.
Now, the documentation says:

> Make sure to place the $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin directory (or the equivalent directory for your OS) in your $PATH so the laravel executable can be located by your system.

To set up $PATH variable I have added this line of code in ~/.bashrc file:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

But, when I type laravel the terminal says:

```
laravel: command not found
```

I searched similar question but couldn't find the right $PATH variable for my OS which is Linux Mint 18.
Can you tell me the right $PATH variable or equivalent directory for my OS?
Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing more searching, Finally I got the answer to my own question. I find it here:
[composer path for Linux Mint 18](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39805823/5041988) 
 This line of code should be added at the bottom of ~/.bashrc fie:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
```

Answer (score 1):

After install laravel using ' composer global require "laravel/installer" '
use the code code below. Its worked for me.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"

Answer (score 0):

Make sur composer is configured
    composer global require "laravel/installer"

Then, you have to install Laravel first, with this command

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

Comment: And make sure composer by typing :

Comment: I already installed this laravel installer by this command. I am facing problem to set $PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search will do. Check the link below:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=180380

Comment: I can't see anything related to "Laravel" on that page!

Comment: I know how to set PATH environment variable. In this case, I need to know the directory or exact location of Laravel Installer in my OS.