# Could not find package /laravel/laravel with stability stable

Tags: php, linux, laravel

```
Could not find package /laravel/laravel with stability stable.
```

So I've got that error when I tried to create new laravel project with the following command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist /laravel/laravel project
```

And if I try just laravel new project, I get:
laravel: command not found

However laravel is installed, and if I move to its installation folder (which is ~/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer), and I type:

```
php laravel new project
```

Then it works but I get bunch of * suggests installing *. For example:

```
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (Required to use psr7 bridging features (0.2.*).)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using expression matching)
psy/psysh suggests installing hoa/console (A pure PHP readline implementation. You'll want this if your PHP install doesn't already support readline or libedit.)
```

And many more.

I'm on Linux Mint Cinnamon 64-bit, and LAMP.

Comment: There shouldn't be an extra slash in `/laravel/laravel`. It should just be `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project`. You also need to add your global composer packages location to your $PATH environment variable in order to use them.

Comment: Okay, just managed to create project with composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project. Can you tell me where are composer global packages? Are all in ~/config/composer/vendor/bin? But if I run it from there I stll must use: "php laravel". But I should be able just "laravel", right?

Comment: Not without adding it to your $PATH variable, you're not. You can find out where your global packages are by running `composer config --list --global`. You can also find out if you installed the package globally by running `composer global show` and seeing if `laravel/installer` is listed. If not, you didn't install it properly. If it is, then [read this to see how to add the appropriate path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373188/laravel-installation-how-to-place-the-composer-vendor-bin-directory-in-your). Also, [read the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything you need is covered in [Laravel's extensive documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation).

> **Via Composer Create-Project**
>
> Alternatively, you may also install Laravel by issuing the Composer
>   create-project command in your terminal:
>
> `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

Note that there is no preceding slash in `laravel/laravel`.

For the installer to work, again you can refer to the documentation:

> **Via Laravel Installer**
>
> First, download the Laravel installer using Composer:
>
> `composer global require "laravel/installer"` Make sure to place the
>   `$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin directory` (or the equivalent directory for
>   your OS) in your $PATH so the laravel executable can be located by
>   your system.
>
> Once installed, the laravel new command will create a fresh Laravel
>   installation in the directory you specify. For instance, laravel new
>   blog will create a directory named blog containing a fresh Laravel
>   installation with all of Laravel's dependencies already installed:
>
> `laravel new blog`

You can read more about changing your $PATH variable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373188/laravel-installation-how-to-place-the-composer-vendor-bin-directory-in-your)

Comment: thanks, I've rerun laravel installer and now it's okay, or it seems so by now