# How to resolve 'Could not find package laravel/laravel with stability stable' error when creating a new project in Laravel using Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-8

I want to create a new project in laravel but an error occurs.

When I download all the packages, the same error occurs

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
```

```
Could not find package laravel/laravel with stability stable.
```

My `composer diag` output:

```
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK git version 2.32.0
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: 
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: OK
Composer version: 2.5.7
PHP version: 8.1.19
PHP binary path: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.19/bin/php
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1t  7 Feb 2023
cURL version: 8.1.1 libz 1.2.11 ssl (SecureTransport) OpenSSL/1.1.1t
zip: extension present, unzip present, 7-Zip not available
```

I want to create a new project in laravel but an error occurs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find package /laravel/laravel with stability stable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349538/could-not-find-package-laravel-laravel-with-stability-stable)

Comment: @lezhni , Unfortunately (

Comment: Did you tried to add `--prefer-dist` flag to install command?

Comment: @lezhni. Yes, 
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
same error: 
                                                                 
  Could not find package laravel/laravel with stability stable.

Comment: @AzerAbbasov: Please add those clarifications to your question (insert `---` to create a segment or similar) by editing it, don't place that into commments. The suggested answer also contains installing with the installer. Have you tried that?