# .composer file (in the home directory) is not created even after I installed Composer and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install php framework, [Laravel](https://laravel.com) on my Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop. I followed the documentation and installed composer. I moved the `composer.phar` file to `/usr/local/composer`. After I excecuted

```
$composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

But I could neither find .composer file in $HOME nor could I execute

```
$laravel
```

On my terminal

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean but try the Via Composer Create-Project `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

Comment: it works that way.. but i won't be able to use laravel in my command promt

Comment: Ok I get you I think. Have you tried this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373188/laravel-installation-how-to-place-the-composer-vendor-bin-directory-in-your